# Can fabric use telnet for run() commands?

Tags: python, telnet, fabric

I've used fabric in the past for web development, but presently I'm doing some work on an embedded system that does not have ssh, but does have telnet.

I have a lot of testing/installation tasks that can benefit from automation, so I was wondering:

*Is there a way to get fabric to use telnet for its run() and sudo() commands?*

Is there a tool in a similar vein to fabric that could be used with telnet?  I'm really just trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel to solve a minor nuisance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) library that will let you do process automation. You can use it to automate stuff like telnet, ftp, vi. For telnet specifically check out [this script](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/152043-simple-telnet-session-scripting/). That should be all you need to automate the process. You can put your pexpect code into a fabric task and then use fabric that way. But I'm not sure you would get much extra value by taking this approach.